# MimeMessage can't use inner class

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

We are trying to run some standard Java code to send a message via Javamail from a 3rd part application, problem we have is there is a bug in the application meaning it isn't able to use inner classes.

Before anyone asks, please don't ask to fix the application, as it's not within our control. The company who owns the application has suggested others resolve the issue by creating a separate class, instead of using the inner class of `RecipientType` within `setRecipients`.

We have tried to no avail to get this to work, creating a new class for `RecipientType`, although we are having trouble referencing it as it's not a method within `setRecipients`.

Would be grateful if anyone has an idea of how to get round having to use an inner class within `MimeMessage`? Is there a way we can hard code this?

Additional info:

This is what we are calling in the application

```java
// new MIME message, version 1.0:

javax.mail.Message message = new javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage(session);

message.setHeader("MIME-Version" , "1.0" );

message.setFrom(new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress, fromEmailPersonal ));

message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(  recipientEmailAddress ));

message.setSubject( emailSubject );

message.setText(emailBody);

javax.mail.Transport.send(message);
```

This is the section of Message.java that is failing

```java
    /**
     * This inner class defines the types of recipients allowed by
     * the Message class. The currently defined types are TO,
     * CC and BCC.
     *
     * Note that this class only has a protected constructor, thereby
     * restricting new Recipient types to either this class or subclasses.
     * This effectively implements an enumeration of the allowed Recipient
     * types.
     *
     * The following code sample shows how to use this class to obtain
     * the "TO" recipients from a message.
     * <blockquote><pre>
     *
     * Message msg = folder.getMessages(1);
     * Address[] a = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
     *
     * </pre></blockquote>
     *
     * @see javax.mail.Message#getRecipients
     * @see javax.mail.Message#setRecipients
     * @see javax.mail.Message#addRecipients
     */
    public static class RecipientType implements Serializable {
    /**
     * The "To" (primary) recipients.
     */
    public static final RecipientType TO = new RecipientType("To");
    /**
     * The "Cc" (carbon copy) recipients.
     */
    public static final RecipientType CC = new RecipientType("Cc");
    /**
     * The "Bcc" (blind carbon copy) recipients.
     */
    public static final RecipientType BCC = new RecipientType("Bcc");

    /**
     * The type of recipient, usually the name of a corresponding
     * Internet standard header.
     *
     * @serial
     */
    protected String type;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7479791750606340008L;

    /**
     * Constructor for use by subclasses.
     *
     * @param   type    the recipient type
     */
    protected RecipientType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * When deserializing a RecipientType, we need to make sure to
     * return only one of the known static final instances defined
     * in this class.  Subclasses must implement their own
     * <code>readResolve</code> method that checks for their known
     * instances before calling this super method.
     *
     * @return  the RecipientType object instance
     * @exception   ObjectStreamException for object stream errors
     */
    protected Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        if (type.equals("To"))
        return TO;
        else if (type.equals("Cc"))
        return CC;
        else if (type.equals("Bcc"))
        return BCC;
        else
        throw new InvalidObjectException(
            "Attempt to resolve unknown RecipientType: " + type);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type;
    }
    }
```

This is the custom class we tried to implement in place of the inner class, labelled RecipientType

```java
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.ParseException;

 public class RecipientType implements Serializable {
    /**
     * The "To" (primary) recipients.
     */
    public static final RecipientType TO = new RecipientType("To");
    /**
     * The "Cc" (carbon copy) recipients.
     */
    public static final RecipientType CC = new RecipientType("Cc");
    /**
     * The "Bcc" (blind carbon copy) recipients.
     */
    public static final RecipientType BCC = new RecipientType("Bcc");

    /**
     * The type of recipient, usually the name of a corresponding
     * Internet standard header.
     *
     * @serial
     */
    protected String type;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7479791750606340008L;

    /**
     * Constructor for use by subclasses.
     *
     * @param   type    the recipient type
     */
    protected RecipientType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * When deserializing a RecipientType, we need to make sure to
     * return only one of the known static final instances defined
     * in this class.  Subclasses must implement their own
     * <code>readResolve</code> method that checks for their known
     * instances before calling this super method.
     *
     * @return  the RecipientType object instance
     * @exception   ObjectStreamException for object stream errors
     */
    protected Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        if (type.equals("To"))
        return TO;
        else if (type.equals("Cc"))
        return CC;
        else if (type.equals("Bcc"))
        return BCC;
        else
        throw new InvalidObjectException(
            "Attempt to resolve unknown RecipientType: " + type);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

This is how we tried implementing the custom class

```
message.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, 
javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(  recipientEmailAddress ));
```

We get the following error:
Unable to parse expression; undefined method: addRecipient for class: javax.mal.Message (line: 29, col:2)

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to do. Can you show us the code with the inner class that fails right now (and possibly also show us *how* it fails, like exception messages). And then ideally also what your alternative approach looks like and which part you are stuck with. Basically: **we can't fix the code without seeing the code.**

Comment: _Absolute wild guess_: **Static** inner classes as when they would implement Serializable, the outer class should be serializable, and serialisation would take too much with it.